# compare method list with array

Tags: c#, priority-queue, icomparer

**Background to the problem:**

Im currently working on a pathfinder. My lastest implementation was the ability to load in different mapfiles instead of only using one array containing the map. So before it looked like this:

```
Node[] mMatrix;
```

However since I want to load in different segments of nodes. I made this:

```
List<Node[]>
```

The class, Node simply contains an int declared as F.

**And now to the issue!**

*To be short, the specific question is how would you compare an object of type : List< Node[] > in the IComparer Members Compare method.*

I have been using a priorityQueue for speeding up the pathfinder algorithm but now Im having issues with comparing this new "2 dimensional" datastructure.
For my **old working** implementation i used this:

```
internal class ComparePFNodeMatrix : IComparer<int>
{
    //Variables Declaration
    Node[] mMatrix;

    //Constructors
    public ComparePFNodeMatrix(Node[] matrix)
    {
        mMatrix = matrix;
    }

    //IComparer Members
    public int Compare(int a, int b)
    {
        if (mMatrix[a].F > mMatrix[b].F)
            return 1;
        else if (mMatrix[a].F < mMatrix[b].F)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Anyone knowing how to make a comparer with the new datastructure Im using?
Thanks on advance!

Comment: you get list `List<Node[]> n2 = (List<Node[]>)b;` and try get field `F ` from list, `n1.F` this `n1` is List, not Node

Comment: [Please do not put tags in your question title.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: To implement `IComparer<int>`, you need a `Compare(int, int)` method, which makes your new Compare method completely useless. You probably need to operate on a different level; after all how can you simply compare two lists of arrays of objects? It looks like a quite complex issue.

Comment: Allright! Thank you very much. Do you have any recommendations of what appraoch I should use? I do certainly agree with you that it is a complex issue.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have changed `Node[] mMatrix;` to `List<Node[]> mMatrix;`. If that's the case,

`mMatrix[a]` gives you the `Node[]` and not the `Node`.
If you want to access `F` you have to use something like:

```
int i = (mMatrix[a])[anotherIndex].F;
```

**EDIT 1:**
And if you are using `List<Node[]> n1 = (List<Node[]>)a;` then how can you access `F` with simply `n1.F`? `n1` is of type `List<Node[]>` and not `Node`. It's as straightforward as it can get.

Comment: Certainly! The issue now is then, how do I make a Priorityqueue support a kind of 2D array? I bet it´s not possible using the compare method since it only has 2 parameters?